# How to records by latest date using Map Reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm recently start learning map reduce programming. So for these purpose I started with one scenario. Where I'm having sample data like account number, balance & date of transaction. So I want latest transaction occurred by account number.

**This is my input:**

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| accno | bal   | date       |
+-------+-------+------------+
| 13611 |  3360 | 2015-09-18 |
| 13611 |  1500 | 2015-09-19 |
| 13620 | 10000 | 2015-09-17 |
| 13620 |  6000 | 2015-09-18 |
| 13620 |  3000 | 2015-09-19 |
| 13631 |  5000 | 2015-09-16 |
| 13631 |  3500 | 2015-09-18 |
| 13621 |  3000 | 2015-09-10 |
| 13621 |  1800 | 2015-09-15 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

**Expected Output -->**

```
    +-------+-------+------------+
    | accno | bal   | Date       |
    +-------+-------+------------+
    | 13611 |  1500 | 2015-09-19 |
    | 13620 |  3000 | 2015-09-19 |
    | 13631 |  3500 | 2015-09-18 |
    | 13621 |  1800 | 2015-09-15 |
    +-------+-------+------------+
```

I'm trying to develop code, but I'm stuck with how to get latest date for particular key. As process

1) I read input and emits acc_no as a key & line of text as a value.

2) Then I'm partitioning data on key(i.e acc_no)

3) In reduce phase implementing logic to get records by latest date.

**//Driver code**

```
public class EmployeeDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

    @Override
    public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());

//      job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(EmployeeMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setPartitionerClass(EmployessPartitioner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(EmployeeReducer.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(4);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("D:\\datatoload\\HotelCloutMap\\Emplyoee\\Input\\in.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("D:\\datatoload\\HotelCloutMap\\Emplyoee\\output"));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 : 1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new EmployeeDriver(), args));
    }
}
```

// Mapper

```
public class EmployeeMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{
    LongWritable l = null;
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String[] line = value.toString().split(",");
        l = new LongWritable(Long.parseLong(line[0]));
        System.out.println(key + " "+ value);
        context.write(l, value);
    }
}
```

// Reducer

```
public class EmployeeReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{

    public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int cnt =0;
        String date ="",sal = "";
        for(Text val : value){
             String [] str = val.toString().split(",");
             sal = str[1];
             date = str[2];
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(sal+" "+date));
    }
}
```

//Partitioner

```
public class EmployessPartitioner extends Partitioner<LongWritable, Text>{
    @Override
    public int getPartition(LongWritable key, Text value, int numOfReduceTasks) {
        String[] line = value.toString().split(",");
        int acc_no = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);

         if(numOfReduceTasks == 0)
         {
            return 0;
         }
        if(acc_no == 13611)
            return 0;
        else if(acc_no == 13620)
            return 1;
        else if(acc_no == 13631)
            return 2;
        else
            return 3;
    }
}
```

My program giving me output like this

```
13611   3360 2015-09-18
13620   10000 2015-09-17
13631   5000 2015-09-16
13621   3000 2015-09-10
```

So how i get latest records for account number.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have to implement secondry sort in your MR program to sort date and pick the latest one. I would suggest to go for Hive/Pig when you have tabular data as you already have good collection of queries and function to perform complex analysis. This will save lot of time in coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve is using the `secondary sorting`, which you need to write an custom `grouping comparable` which will sort the values for you. This happens just before the data is passed to the Reducer for the processing. The secondary sort, sorts the values corresponding to the key. This sorted list is passed to the Reducer.

```
public class BalanceDate implements Writable {
   LongWritable balance;
   Text date;

   public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
   }

   public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
   }
}
```

Write a custom comparable which implements `WritableComparable<BalanceDate/Text>` and set the class in job configuration. Sort the date part of the values in descending order and just read the first value from the list in reducer.

```
job.setGroupingComparatorClass(DateComparator.class);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try with the way you provide me.

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde  I have just given you the outline. Please search more about how to implement and do it. It will be interesting learning.